# Small bump with transform scale and transform-origin

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I've been struggling to understand why when i'm trying to do a transform scale with transform-origin: top, the animation starts with bumping the object up a little bit.

I have this snippet for example. the transition is long to emphasize the problem.
Thanks!

```css
.plus-sign {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #3b3b3b;
  outline: 3px solid white;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
}

.plus-sign:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: top;
  border: 1px solid #ff6250;
}
```

```html
    <div class="plus-sign"></div>
```

Comment: When I changed border: 1px -> 2px in :hover, bumping did not happen

Comment: I don't see any problems here, which browser are you using?

Comment: @SamBruton Chrome 95.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `transform-origin: left top;` This will keep it within the body. Also, going up half a pixel on the border minimized all bumping behavior.

```css
.plus-sign {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #3b3b3b;
  outline: 3px solid white;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
}

.plus-sign:hover {
  transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: left top;
  border: 1.5px solid #ff6250;
}
```

```html
<div class="plus-sign"></div>
```